# Non-isomorphic localized rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I want to know why $\mathbb{R}[x,y]_{x^2+y^2}\not\cong\mathbb{R}[x,y]_{xy}$?

(I mean $\mathbb{R}[x,y,(x^2+y^2)^{-1}]\not\cong \Bbb{R}[x,y,(xy)^{-1}]$)

I'm reading about weil restriction. Let $G_{m,k}$ be the multiplicative group, where $k$ is field and $\mathbb{S}:= R_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}G_{m,\mathbb{C}}$ to be the Weil restriction of $G_{m,\mathbb{C}}$. Now, I'm trying to prove that $\mathbb{S}\not\cong G_{m,\mathbb{R}}\times G_{m,\mathbb{R}}$(as affine algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{R}$).

My attempt: I was thinking of finding some maximal ideal $m$ such that $m/m^2$ has different $\mathbb{R}-$dimension in the above two rings.

Comment: The notation $R_{(f)}$ can mean a couple different things - either the localization at the (prime) ideal $(f)$ or the homogeneous localization at the homogeneous element $f$. Which do you mean in your post? Next, this problem is rather light on [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) right now - you'll have a lot better chance at getting an answer and avoiding closure/downvotes if you improve it a bit.

Comment: Thanks @KReiser for the information. I have edited my post

Comment: That's better. But you probably should be asking about the localization at an element - localization at an ideal is defined for prime ideals, and $(xy)$ isn't prime. I'd suggest looking instead at the groups of units of these rings, instead of the maximal ideals.

Comment: @KReiser Yeah sorry, my bad. Can you please elaborate your answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there were an isomorphism of rings $\mathbb{R}[x,y]_{x^2 + y^2} \cong \mathbb{R}[x,y]_{xy}$ then there would be an induced isomorphism of their unit groups.

Since $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ is a UFD and $x^2 + y^2$ is irreducible, the units of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]_{x^2 + y^2}$ are precisely the elements of the form $r (x^2 + y^2)^m$ where $0 \not= r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Hence the group of units of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]_{x^2 + y^2}$ is $\mathbb{R}^{\times} \times \mathbb{Z}$.  (The first factor is the non-zero reals with multiplicative group structure, the second factor is the integers with additive group structure).

Similarly one calculates that the group of units of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]_{xy}$ is $\mathbb{R}^{\times} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

The problem thus reduces to checking that there is no group isomorphism $\mathbb{R}^{\times} \times \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{R}^{\times} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.  In fact there are no such surjections.
To check this you could proceed as follows: suppose that such a surjection exists and let $(q,a), (r, b)$ be the elements mapping to $(1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1)$.
This implies that $(q^b/r^a, 0)$ maps to $(1, b, a)$.  Since $n$th roots exist in $\mathbb{R}$, conclude that $a,b$ are divisible by arbitrarily large integers, hence $a = b = 0$.  But then $(q, 0)$ maps to $(1,1,0)$, which by the same reasoning is absurd.

Comment: I agree that the group of units of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]_{x^2+y^2}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\times}\times\mathbb{Z}$ but, I'm not sure if the group of units of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]_{xy}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\times}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. For e.g., take $(r,-1,2)\in\mathbb{R}^{\times}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, in the ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y]_{xy}$, it represents the element $\frac{ry^2}{x(xy)^n}$, for some $n$, but this element doesn't belong to the ring

Comment: @FreePawn $(r, -1, 2)$ corresponds to $r y^2/x$ in your representation of the unit group. Also, remember that when you invert $xy$ you necessarily invert both $x$ and $y$.  So yes, $ry^2/(x(xy)^n)$ is an element of your ring, and you could rewrite it as $r y^3 / (xy)^{n+1}$  if you prefer.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @FreePawn on that note $\mathbb{R}[x,y]_{xy}$ is just the regular old ring of Laurent polynomials in two variables, equivalently the group ring (over $\mathbb{R}$) of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: That's a useful information.

Comment: Dear FreePawn: I'm sure you are happy with Badam Baplan's high quality answer and I suggest that you click on the check sign in the margin of his text to show that you "accept" it. Acceptance is a nice feature of this site, allowing you to gracefully thank a participant for the work he did to give a satisfactory answer to your (excellent) question.